How would a planet with 12 luna sized moons work, orbitally speaking?
I have a planet around 0.8x the size of earth(in terms of volume, but with a higher density to maintain the same level of gravity.) orbited by 12 luna like moons (sameish density, samish size). These 12 moons all occupy the same orbit around the planet and are close enough that large features are recognizable on the surface. How could these moons remain in a stable orbit without interfering with each other too much?
EDIT narrowed the focus to being only about the orbit. The rest I'll handwave away with magic or smth

Surprised that orbital instability wasn't mentioned first. Well, if they were all engineered to stay where they were, had station-keeping rockets or suchlike....

Narrowed down the question. It should be much less problematic(I hope).

I've retracted my close vote. Thank you. However, this might be more easily solved by using an orbit simulator (or, as @Escapeddentalpatient. suggests, you might become more quickly convinced that moons so large around a planet so small orbiting so close is unstable). We link to some simulators in our List of Worldbuilding Resources.

Worlds with large numbers of similarly sized giant moons are a fantasy staple. If that's what you want, just do it and don't worry about it. Your world and its moons don't even have to be space rocks. Your space doesn't even have to be space. All the celestial bodies seen in the sky of The Elder Scrolls games are gestalt psychic manifestations caused by the influence of the interaction of supernatural domains upon the minds of mortals.

It sounds like the question keeps changing. The way it's currently described, the only answer is a "central configuration" orbit. I think this question is better suited to the physics or astronomy stack exchanges. I'm wondering if you could do a rosette like that with horseshoe orbits.

@RobertRapplean It only changed once in response to my concern that the OP's original request violated the Book Rule. The OP's change has brought the question into conformance, although whether or not it's better suited for [astronomy.se] I can't address.

What kind of physics are you looking for here?

 What kind of physics are you looking for here? 

Orbital physics.
 It sounds like the question keeps changing. The way it's currently described, the only answer is a "central configuration" orbit. I think this question is better suited to the physics or astronomy stack exchanges. I'm wondering if you could do a rosette like that with horseshoe orbits. 

Maybe...

@nadichamp.  I think that my answer from early in the morning of December 14, 2024 is the most informative.

Let me clarify my question. Are you looking for the physics like we have in our universe, or a completely different kind of physics?

@elemtilas Our universe, there are magical forces present in my world, however not on a large enough scale to really affect planetary physics.

Hmm. Okay. In that case, I think you've got your answers.

There is blog called:
https://planetplanet.net/
By astrophysicist Sean Raymond.  It has a section where Raymond tries to design imaginary star systems with as many habitable planets as is scientifically possible.  The more habitable planets there are in such a system, the more improbable and rarer such systems will be, and some are so improbable that they would have to be built by some super advanced civilization instead of forming naturally.
https://planetplanet.net/the-ultimate-solar-system/
In a post dated May 3, 2017 "The Ultimate Engineered Solar System":
https://planetplanet.net/2017/05/03/the-ultimate-engineered-solar-system/
Raymond cites a paper from 2010 by Smith and Lissaeur which shows that multiple bodies can share the same orbit around another body.
https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010CeMDA.107..487S/abstract
Many space objects can share an orbit around a larger object if they are equally spaced and are separated along the orbit by at least 12 of their Hill radii.
An object the size of the Moon, namely the Moon, orbits the Earth at a distance equal to the Moon's orbit, and at that distance the Moon is close enough that very large features on its surface can be see with the unaided human eye, and many more features can be seen with even amateur telescopes.
I have a notebook somewhere with a drawing I made of the full Moon one day in 1977 at Cape May, New Jersey, with my unaided eyes.  It shows the large dark features on the Moon.  And on December 12 or 13, 2024, I looked at the Moon with unaided vision and was pleased to see that I could still see the dark regions on the Moon, even the two small dark regions, Mare Nectaris and Mare Fecunditatis, attached to Marie Tranquilities.
So if the set of 12 Luna-sized moons orbit the planet at the same distance as the Moon orbits Earth, large features on their surfaces will be visible from the surface of the planet.
The Moon's orbit has a semi-major axis of 384,399 kilometers.  Thus if the Moon's orbit was perfectly circular the orbit would have a circumference of 2,415,248.09 kilometers.  So 12 equally spaced moons along that orbit would be spaced about 201,270.7 kilometers apart.  So would that be more than 12 of their Hill radii apart, giving them long term stable orbits?
Here is link to a Hill sphere radius calculator.
https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/hill-sphere-radius
In this cases I set the orbit of the "planet" to be 384,399 kilometers and the mass of the "planet" to be that of the Moon, 0.0123 that of Earth.
I set the mass of the "star", in this case the planet the 12 moons orbit, at an arbitrary 0.9 times the mass of Earth, and got a Hill radius of 57,350.676 kilometers. 12 times that would be a spacing of 688,208 kilometers, giving room for only 3.5 moons to share the orbit.
The question asks for a planet with 0.8 times the volume of Earth, but with a higher  density, enough to give it the same "gravity", presumably meaning surface gravity.
A planet with 0.928 the radius of Earth would have 0.799 the volume of Earth.
According to this surface gravity calculator
https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/acceleration-due-to-gravity
A planet with 0.928 the radius of Earth and 0.86 the mass of Earth would have a surface gravity of about 1 g.
Putting 0.86 the mass of Earth into the Hill sphere calculator, I find it gives a Hill radius of 64,049.033 kilometers for each of the Luna-mass moons and a necessary separation of 768,588.396 kilometers.
So I try giving each moon half the mass of the Moon.  An object with the same density as the Moon but half the volume and half the mass (0.00615 the mass of Earth) would have a diameter 0.795 that of the Moon, which would be a bit more than three quarters.
That gives a hill radius of 50,835.751 kilometers and a necessary separation of 610,029.012 kilometers.  That allows for 3.959 equally spaced moons sharing the orbit.
Then I tried making each moon 0.5 the diameter of the Moon, thus giving them 0.125 the mass of the moon or 0.00015375 the mass of Earth.  That gives them a Hill radius of 14,864.464 kilometers, and a necessary separation of 178,373.568 kilometers. So an orbital circumference of 2,415,248.09 kilometers will have room for 13.54 such moons.
I note that if those moons with half the diameter of the Moon orbited at one half the semi-major axis of the Moon's orbit they would appear just as large as the Moon appears from Earth when they were seen from the surface of their planet.  Half the semi-major axis of the Moon's orbit would be about 192,199.5 kilometers and the circumference of the orbit would be about 1,207,624.054 kilometers.
In that case the Hill sphere radius would be about 7,432.232 kilometers and the minimum separation would be about 89,186.784 kilometers.  There would be room for 13.54 equally spaced moons in the orbit.
Suppose the moons with one half the diameter of the Moon, and thus 0.00015375 the mass of Earth, orbited the planet at one quarter the semi-major axis of the Moon's orbit, and thus had twice the apparent diameter of the Moon as seen from Earth.
A quarter of the semi-major axis of the Moon's orbit would be 96,099.75 kilometers and the orbit would have a circumference of about 603,812.0272 kilometers.  The Hill radius of each Moon would be 3,716.116 kilometers and the minimum separation along the orbit would be 44,593.392 kilometers, and there would be room for 13.54 equally space moons in the orbit.
Thus if the ratio between the masses of the central body and the orbiting body remains the same, the Hill radius of the orbiting body, and thus the required spacing of bodies sharing the orbit, will have the proportion to the circumference of the orbit, and thus the maximum number of bodies which can share the orbit will be constant.
And it would be possible for an almost Earth mass planet to have 12 moons sharing an orbit around the planet and appearing from the surface of that planet to have the same angular diameter, or greater, as the Moon has when seen from Earth.  And thus surface features of those moons would be as visible from the planet's surface as surface features of the Moon are from the surface of the Earth.
But of course Mark's answer is correct that it would have to be an artificial system of moons created by super advanced beings.

short answer: those moons couldn't maintain a stable orbit.
long answer: tidal forces would rip apart the planet and the moons if you tried to force them into such a system.
And that's all there is to it, sorry. You might be able to put a small number of Phobos sized moonlets in the same orbit, maybe a bit larger, but not anything close to the size of our moon.

Thanks for the answer, guess I'll have to go with a less science-based solution.

@Jwenting I think that my answer from early in the morning of December 14, 2024 is the most informative.

@M.A.Golding Thanks, yours is really helpful.

The closest thing to a stable solution for twelve moons in the same orbit around a planet is the Klemperer rosette: equally-spaced, and either equally-sized or with an alternating big-small pattern.  Since a rosette is unstable, this would need to be someone's cosmic art project, not a naturally-occurring phenomenon.
